# Get csv file in realm database with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, csv, realm

I have a csv file which looks like this

```
Tag1,Tag2,Tag3,
some1,some2,some3,
some4,some5,some6,
```

is there a way to import this file to the realm database programatically?

Like everytime the app starts the new csv file should be imported in the realm database.

The `Tag1,Tag2,Tag3,` should be the column headers and the `some...` should be the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out-of-the box solution at the moment for programatically importing contents of a `csv` file to an existing `realm` file.

You can use Realm Studio to create a new realm file from a csv file. [Realm Cocoa Converter](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter) can also be used to generate a new realm file from one or more csv files, however, to be able to import files into an already existing realm file, you'd need to modify the converter. Bear in mind that Realm Cocoa Converter only support macOS, it cannot be used in an iOS project.

Or you can write your own code for converting a `csv` file to `Realm` `Object`s. Parsing a CSV file is quite easy, validating it to make sure it can be converted to Realm objects is a bit more complicated. However, from JSON/plist you could automatically parse Realm objects using `Codable`.

Comment: Just to add .02 for future readers; while the Realm Studio app does not have an an import function, the OP asked if it can be done *programatically*. So while this is an accepted answer, for clarification there are many ways to import contents of a file programatically, and csv files are pretty easy to work with so moving the contents of a csv file programatically to Realm is about 10 lines of code plus a realm object. So based on *Like everytime the app starts the new csv file should be imported in the realm database.* it can be done within the project.

Comment: @Jay you're right, I should have been more precise. There's no out-of-the box solution, that's what I meant. Obviously the problem can be solved programatically. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

My macOS app imports contents of a `tsv` file to an existing realm file . Here is my function to read a file.

```swift
func readFileFrom(_ fileURL: URL) -> [[String]]? {
  do {
    let content = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: .utf8)
    let data: [[String]] = content.components(separatedBy: "\r\n").map { $0.components(separatedBy: "\t") }
    return data
  } catch {
    //
  }
  return nil
}
```

I then pass the returned data to my Realm manager class that generates and adds new objects.

```
guard let data = readFileFrom(url) else { return }
RealmManager.write(data: data)
```

For `csv` files, you can change `components(separatedBy: "\t")` to `components(separatedBy: ",")`.

Comment: This could be a better answer to accept based on the question. The OP asked how to *import this file to the realm database programatically* and this answer shows exactly how to do that task.